# How do partition size affect read/write performances in Cassandra?

Tags: performance, cassandra, partitioning, cassandra-3.0

I can partition my table into a small amount of bigger partitions or several smaller partitions, but in my use case the big partition is still small in size, it will never exceed 100MB. There will be millions of users reading from this table so is there a risk of congestion when having so many users reading from a single partition?

I can imagine that splitting the read queries between several physical nodes is faster than reading from a single physical node, but does splitting read queries between several virtual nodes improve performance in the same way? The number of big partitions will exceed the number of physical nodes, so will spreading the data further through the virtual nodes with smaller partitions improve the read performance? Is the answer any different for updating partitions of counter tables?

So basically, what I need to know is if millions of users reading from the same partition (that is below 100MB in size) will introduce congestion. This is the answer that actually matters for my project. But I also want to know if spreading the data further (regular and counter tables), beyond the number of physical nodes through smaller partitions will increase the read/write performance.

Any reference links would be extremely appreciated since I'll be writing a report and referencing an article, journal or documentation is always preferred.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion accessing the same partition ( We are actually talking about "row" in cassandra 3.0) is not a problem. If the load on your cluster is increasing then you just need to add more node, this is the no single point of failure principle. Each node in your cluster is able to fulfil the user request ( depending on your replication factor and read consistency).

Also if you know that a partition key is going to be accessed a lot then you can play with the key and row cache functionality of your table, you will avoid any disk access